# Using pinch gestures to zoom into custom graph

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, graph, zooming

I'm using CoreGraphics to draw a graph from data from two `NSArray` objects (one array containing the horizontal data, one containing the vertical data). While this works okay, I'd like to implement a zoom feature so that when a user pinches on the graph, the viewable data zooms according to their pinch.

So that a pinch out like this:
[image]

Becomes this:
[image]

I've already got a variable called `dataRange`, which when the graph is rendered, it is restricted to this range of values. `dataRange` is an `NSRange`, meaning it is specified by a start position and a length. However, I'm unsure how to calculate these values as the user is pinching out to produce the zooming effect.

After thinking about how I could achieve this, I came up with the following:

1. Determine each finger's location on the screen, and figure out a what elements in the array I would need to zoom into
2. As the position moves closer and closer towards the sides of the graph, set the range of the visible data accordingly

However, there have been a few issues with that method. Firstly, it ignores whether or not the graph has been zoomed in previously, meaning that users are unable to zoom in more than once. It also does the opposite than what you would expect, as pinching in increases the range of the visible data (zooms out), and pinching out means decreases the range of the visible data (zooms in). I'd like the opposite of this.

The code which does this is implemented inside `-touchesMoved:withEvent`:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    if ([allTouches count] == 2) {
        CGFloat xPositionStart = 0.0f, xPositionEnd = 0.0f;
        CGFloat touchPositions[2] = {0.0f, 0.0f};

        for (UITouch *object in allTouches) {
            CGPoint touchLocation = [object locationInView:self];

            if (touchPositions[0] == 0.0f) {
                touchPositions[0] = touchLocation.x;
            } else {
                touchPositions[1] = touchLocation.x;
            }
        }

        if (touchPositions[0] > touchPositions[1]) {
            xPositionEnd = touchPositions[0];
            xPositionStart = touchPositions[1];
        } else {
            xPositionStart = touchPositions[0];
            xPositionEnd = touchPositions[1];
        }

        CGFloat xPositionStartActual = (xPositionStart / self.frame.size.width) * [self.horizontalValues count];
        CGFloat xPositionEndActual = (xPositionEnd / self.frame.size.width) * [self.horizontalValues count];

        self.dataRange = NSMakeRange(xPositionStartActual, xPositionEndActual - xPositionStartActual);
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

I'm kind of stuck as I am unable to find a way to resolve these issues with my current method. I'd appreciate it if anybody could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you place your graph view inside a scroll view that can handle your zooming, can't it?

Comment: In order for more information about the graph to become visible (instead of just scaling the information presently on the graph, like an image), I need to redraw the graph with a specific data range, based upon the user's touches. This means I need to handle the scaling myself.

Comment: Couldn't you just alter your detail level based on the zoom level of the enclosing scroll view? Then you can use scroll view's built-in panning/zooming functionality. There's a delegate method for scroll view: `scrollViewDidZoom:` you can use.

Answer (score 2):

You can make custom zoom using UIPinchGestureRecognizer. This is how I did the same task:

```
- (void)pinchToZoom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    NSUInteger numTouches = [recognizer numberOfTouches], i;
    for ( i = 0; i < numTouches; ++i ) {
        CGPoint location = [recognizer locationOfTouch:i inView:self.view];
        // now you can do something with points of your pinch if you wish
    }

    // next calculate the current zoomScale TAKING INTO ACCOUNT previous value
    if (fabs(previousPinchScale - recognizer.scale) > 0.01) {

        previousPinchScale = recognizer.scale;
        zoomScale = beginScale * recognizer.scale;
        if (zoomScale < minimumCameraScale) zoomScale = minimumCameraScale;
        if (zoomScale > maximumCameraScale) zoomScale = maximumCameraScale;

        // now make the zoom using CGAffineTransform
        CGAffineTransform affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(zoomScale, zoomScale);
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:duration];
        [self.layer setAffineTransform:affineTransform];
        [CATransaction commit];
    }
}
```

Now I explain what every float property I used means:

**previousPinchScale** - a variable that determines if you pinch on some significant scale (more than 0.01). This was made just for not calling setAffineTransform more times, because it is quite slow action. Set previousPinchScale = -1 in your init method.

**beginScale** - a variable for making custom zoom smooth-viewed. You set it in the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if ( [gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]] ) {
        beginScale = zoomScale;
    }
}
```

**zoomScale** - a variable that determines current zoom of your graphic (like the UIScrollView property).

**minimumZoomScale, maximumZoomScale** - should be evident :)

This is the general approach and it zooms the entire graphic. 
If you want to zoom only some part of it, you can apply affineTransform to this part, not to the whole view. If you want to achieve "reverse" effect of zooming, you can just multiply all float values by -1 in additional. You can also add some offset of your graphic based on what points did user pinch it.

I hope all of it helps you somehow.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks @Miroslav your code helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to animate the scale as that zooms everything.  Try zooming the content view's width and height constraints.  Put your graph view inside a scroll view as the content view.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Your answer could be a little more specific, i.e. with code suggestions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Code for this. Based on @Miroslav's answer.

```
var previousPinchScale:CGFloat = -1.0
var zoomScale:CGFloat = 1.0
var beginScale:CGFloat = 1.0

@IBAction func pinchGestureRecognizer(_ recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        beginScale = zoomScale
    }
    
    if (abs(previousPinchScale - recognizer.scale) > 0.01) {
        
        previousPinchScale = recognizer.scale
        zoomScale = beginScale * recognizer.scale
        let minimumScale : CGFloat = 1.0
        let maximumScale : CGFloat = 10.0
        
        if (zoomScale < minimumScale) { zoomScale = minimumScale }
        if (zoomScale >= maximumScale) { zoomScale = maximumScale }
        
        /* Do whatever you want to perform with this zoomScale. 
          I used it as and index to get data from Array and did graph redraw  
        */
    }
}
```